# Use TimeLine to trigger a void method every certain seconds JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, timer, label, timeline

Im trying to update a label every certain seconds, I tried using a normal Timer but since its in another thread it cannot make changes to the label, this is the Timer:

```
 public void setTimer(Timer timer, int seconds, String userName, String content, VBox tabContent,ArrayList<Integer> countTweetsArray, Label statusLabel) {
 TabContent tabContentObj = new TabContent();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         setTweet(userName, content);
         //tabContentObj.createStatusScreen(tabContent, countTweetsArray, remainingTweets);
         System.out.println(content+"  after  "+seconds);
         System.out.println("countTweetsArray: "+countTweetsArray.get(0));
         statusLabel.setText(countTweetsArray.get(0).toString());
         countTweetsArray.set(0, (countTweetsArray.get(0)+1));
         tabContentObj.timersMap.put(userName, timer);
     }
 }, (seconds*1000));
 }
```

I read that I can make periodic changes to a label  using TimeLine but I cant understand how it works the keyvalues and the keyframes, Is there a way to just trigger a void method without any animation involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`KeyFrame` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-) that takes a `Duration` and an event handler:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(seconds), e -> {
        // code to execute here...
    })
);
timeline.play();
```

Update: if you need a button to stop it, you can do that with

```
Button button = new Button("Stop");
button.setOnAction(e -> timeline.stop());
```

Comment: I used a snippet of code like the one in your answer that also used lambda, the problem is that I want to stop the timer with a button and If I tried to declare the timeline object and then pass it to the constructor it said that it needed to be final if i used lambda , do you have any idea how to reference the timeline to stop it?

Comment: If you only assign it a value once, it is "effectively final" and can be used in a lambda. I see no reason you would assign it multiple times anyway. You can always make it an instance variable if you really need.

Comment: Do I put the code you post in the update inside the constructor method?

Comment: Constructor of what? Just put it where you need it.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. I got confused about the "e" in the lambda, I dont use lambda often. Thanks